# Customising page content depending on result of GET request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

We're building an AngularJS application. I'm now building a public form that is customized depending on the URL it's loaded with.

For example

```
http://url.com.au/Registration.cshtml#?org=org1
```

will look slightly different than

```
http://url.com.au/Registration.cshtml#?org=org2
```

When the page loads I would like to load some info with GET http://url.com.au/api/Org/org1
and use the response to drive some UI elements.

At first the differences will be small (URL for logo, values from some checkboxes) but over time the form may be more and more dynamic.

What is the pattern I should follow to support:

1. simple differences,
2. further along the journey a more dynamic ui?

Comment: Maybe use something like https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude, so that you can keep changes in each org's page. The pages you include could have a the same template

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution, I would hold the url change in a route parameter for that route. Then access it using [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams). That way you can change your base GET url easily.

For both simple and dynamic UIs I would try to keep use of ngInclude to a minimum (less files to load = better load times, also it creates a new scope which isn't always ideal).

For simple differences I would structure your html to be as accommodating to both layouts as possible. Think about using ng-show/hide to trigger DOM changes based of variables retrieved from the GET request. For assets like images the GET request could return the path to the image and you can then use [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) to include it.

Further along the journey, you may want to consider having nested routing. [UI-Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/) is a very popular solution.